# Displaying tags after selecting a dropdown

Tags: mysql, jsp, select, drop-down-menu

I have 2 column in mysql database, name and value. there are multiple rows for these columns. I need to display name in a dropdown on a jsp page and depending upon what name is selected, its value should be displayed below. 
Please provide some piece of code.

my piece of code:-

```
<%
  try{
           conn=  ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
           pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("select name, value from myDb ");
           rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
           %>
    <select id="selectDropDown" name="filename" >
        <%  while(rs.next()){  %>
            <option ><%= rs.getString("name")%> </option>
        <% } %>
        </select>
    value :<%= rs.getString("value")%>
    <%
                    } catch (SQLException sq) {
                        out.println("OOps! Something went wrong. DB error!");
                        sq.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        out.println("OOps! Something went wrong.");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
        %>
```

Comment: what have you done so far.. please provide your code..

Comment: piece of codes has been attached..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure how you code, but this is how i code. Maybe you can follow this way to do it. Use two jsp file

### jsp

```
<%
  Vector vName = new Vector();

  String SQL = "SELECT NAME FROM TB_TEST";
  DB_TEST.makeConnection();
  DB_TEST.executeQuery(SQL);
  while(DB_TEST.getNextQuery())
  {
           String sNAME    = DB_TEST.getColumnString("NAME");

          vName.addElement(sNAME);
  }
  DB_TEST.takeDown();
%>
```

### javascript part

```
function fnTest()
{
   var test_value = document.mainform.TEST_NAME.value;
   document.mainform.action = "pop_test2.jsp?value="+test_value;
   document.mainform.submit();
}
```

### html

```
<select name="TEST_NAME" onchange="fnTest();">
<option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
<%
    for (int i=0;i<vNAME.size();i++) {
          String sNAME= (String) vNAME.elementAt(i);
 %>      
    <option value="<%=sNAME%>" ><%= sNAME%></option>
<%}%>  
</select>
<input type="text" name="TEST_VALUE" value="">
```

Once you select the name from drop down list it will redirect to pop_test2.jsp

### pop_test2.jsp

```
<%
  String sNAME  = request.getParameter("value");
  String sVALUE = "";

  String SQL = "SELECT VALUE FROM TB_TEST WHERE NAME='"+sNAME+"' ";
  DB_TEST.makeConnection();
  DB_TEST.executeQuery(SQL);
  while(DB_TEST.getNextQuery())
  {
           sVALUE   = DB_TEST.getColumnString("VALUE");
  }
  DB_TEST.takeDown();
%>
<script language="Javascript">
    parent.document.mainform.TEST_VALUE.value = "<%=sVALUE%>";
</script>
```